# How to get action bar three dots view reference

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

I need to get the `View` representing the three dots on the action bar.

(The reason I want the view reference is to pass it to a showcase library to show the showcaseView.)

No luck finding a solution. Any idea how to do that?

[image]

Comment: You should check out the [TapTargetView](https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView) library. The TapTarget object has a method called forToolbarOverflow that anchors the tool tip to the overflow icon. You can take a look at the source to get an idea for how they did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the 3 dots using the below code. Add the below lines in your layout file.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:paddingLeft="25dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="&#8942;"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textSize="25dp" />
```

> Value in android:text field helps you display the 3 vertical dots
>   known as vertical-ellipsis.

[Click for more details](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/vertical-ellipsis/)

You can use the TextView now to perform your further actions. I hope this is what you are looking for. Comment if you are stuck with anything. Thank-You.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 }
```

Try to add this code in main activity after adding a view activity_main_actions.xml in res/menu like as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<!-- Search / will display always -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but, Please take a look at question again .

Comment: This is not OP is asking.